# How to adjust the length of random password?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random, input-field

Good morning,

I have this code (**just an example**):

```
function random(min, max) {
    return min + parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}
function generatePassword(length, charset) {
    var password = "";
    while (length--) {
        password += charset[random(0, charset.length - 1)];
    }
    return password;
}
function getNewPassword() {
    $('#password').text(generatePassword(12, "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz0123456789!?#@*&.,;:+-=()[]_"));
}
```

And would like to add an input field in HTML, where I can set the length of the generated password.

Can you please find with me a solution? :-)

**http://jsfiddle.net/RnsTq/**

Comment: @maverickosama92: Okay, but can you please answer it with fiddle? ;-)

Comment: do you want to generate a random password with specific length?

Comment: @dare: No, the length should be flexible. So I can change it in an HTML input field.

Comment: @MaximilianFuchs: you should jsfiddle you file so we can adjust it to help you out.
Otherwise we need to reinvent your HTML file and its context…

Comment: Since you removed your last question whilst I was about to propose an improvement I'll post it here instead: http://jsfiddle.net/a2r9k/3/ :)

Comment: @intuitivepixel: You're great! :) Is it possible to put all letters/numbers and special characters in an input field?

Comment: do you mean if it's possible to "type" them in the input field?

Comment: @intuitivepixel: Yes :)

Comment: just played around a bit: http://jsbin.com/odosoy/97/edit something more stylish :) change the charset to what ever you want and see the generated password will contain only the characters from the charset... click generate also multiple times to get more passwords - enjoy

Comment: @intuitivepixel: wow! :) I have an unusual question: Can you please remove the feature by which the passwords are added (and not be replaced; including the 'clear'-button)? I'm sorry that I did not say the features I would liked to have ;-/

Comment: removing is always easy ;) http://jsbin.com/odosoy/125/edit

Comment: @intuitivepixel: Hey;) I want to use this new slider for my password generator because there are more styling options: http://jsfiddle.net/SAHnV/ I don't know how to link it with the JS...? :/ Do you have an idea?

Comment: please, create a different question with the problem ...

Comment: I would, but I have been banned :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you have it: http://jsbin.com/odosoy/94/edit

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#generate").click(function() {
    getNewPassword();
  });

  function random(min, max) {
    return min + parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min + 1), 10);
  }
  function generatePassword(charset) {
    var length = parseInt($("#passlength").val(), 10);
    var password = "";
    while (length--) {
      password += charset[random(0, charset.length - 1)];
    }
    return password;
  }
  function getNewPassword() {
    var pass = generatePassword("AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz0123456789!?#@*&.,;:+-=()[]_");
    $('#password').val(pass);
  }
});
```

### HTML

```
Length: <input id="passlength"/><br>
Password: <input id="password"/><br>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="generate">Generate Password</button>
```

### Update

Just reworked and styled your initial example a bit, nothing really special.
http://jsbin.com/odosoy/97/edit and one in which the password is replaced: http://jsbin.com/odosoy/125/edit

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please put the relevant code in your answer. Demos are nice, but your answer should not rely on external ressources.

Comment: @Bergi, just added, only wanted to be quick in answering since here the answering speed does seams like a HL2 multiplayer game...

Comment: @intuitivepixel: It works! Can you improve something now? jsfiddle.net/RnsTq/2

Comment: @MaximilianFuchs, improved: http://jsfiddle.net/RnsTq/3/ you forgot to add base10 to parseInt in the random function

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the `12` in the call to `generatePassword` use `parseInt($('#len').val(), 10)`, where `len` would be the id of the input element.

Answer (score 1):

look at this:

```
function gen_random(len){
    var charset = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var tempChar = charset.split('');
    for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        password += tempChar[Math.floor(Math.random() * (26+26+10)) + 1];           
    }
    return password;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a new text field and take it's value before you generate your password.

`var passwordLength = $('#maxLength').val();
 $('#password').val(generatePassword(passwordLength, "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz0123456789!?#@*&.,;:+-=()[]_"));`

You can see a quick & dirty fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nininho/pG5A7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to generate a password in JS is to use a lib such as https://github.com/bermi/password-generator

That will generate you a password with a customizable length that even can be memorable.

There's also several example on the link provided.